# build cannot be found under team project

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, tfs

Our coded ui tests take several hours to complete, if I launch run functional tests task from the build definition it looks like it is consuming build minutes and using build pipelines so wrote a small powershell script (and a console application in C#). the plan is to launch either ps1 or console app from the build definition and exit. the ps1 or exe takes a build name as a parameter and launches the vstestconsole with that name as one of the parameters. when I test this locally on azure VM test machine it works fine (updates the results) but when I launch the same through build definition with build name as the parameter I get build cannot be found under team project error:

Log:

```
[command]C:\Users\automation\Desktop\ps1\cmd\ExecuteVSconsole.exe UI_Automation_NoWait_20170621.9
Error: Build "UI_Automation_NoWait_20170621.9" cannot be found under team project "XXX"
arg list :C:\Uiautomationbinaries\UI.dll /logger:Tfspublisher;Collection=https://xxx.visualstudio.com/;BuildName=UI_Automation_NoWait_20170621.9;TeamProject="xxx"
```

The build task I am using is : Powershell on target machine.

The build number is unique (name of the def + day+rev)

I have tried some of the solutions I have found online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since running locally successful, suggest you RDP to the remote machine (the target machine of the task)with your build service account. Then manually run the powershell script to see whether it works.

Also pay attention to the permission of your build service account.

Besides, since you are using azure VM , also follow this tutorial [To set up WinRM for Microsoft Azure Virtual Machines](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines#prerequisites) for *PowerShell on Target Machines task*.